# How to "take out" every multiple of $n$ from a certain function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Create a function $g$ that "takes out" every multiple of $n$ from a certain function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

Or, described more "formally"(at least as "formal" as I can put it, given my limited knowledge of math):

> Create a function $g:\Bbb N\times\Bbb R\setminus n\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R$($\times$ is Cartesian Product) that takes in two arguments $n$ and $x$. This function will only be defined in its domain, while being undefined for every other value of $n,x$. The range(codomain may be more fitting here) of $g$, $\Bbb R$, is referring to the only possible $y$ that can be outputted from any function $g$; your created $g$ doesn't have to have a range of $\Bbb R$. Given a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and a fixed value for $n$, the graph of $g$ and the graph of $f$ should be overlapping exactly, except that the graph of $g$ will be undefined for every $x$ value that is a multiple of $n$. The definition of $g(n,x)$ should include $f(x)$ and $n$ in it. So an example would be $g(n,x)=nf(x)$(this doesn't meet the criteria mentioned, but this is just an example to show what I'm looking for).

I'm not too sure if I have made my question clear enough. Maybe you people out there who are more experienced at math and understand what I'm asking can give some suggestions on how to make my question more clear and correct(like can I really use $n$ to describe the domain for $g$?)? I basically just want $g$ to be $f$ but with every multiple of $n$ "taken out".

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of this task could be, but wouldn't $g(n,x) = \frac{f(x)\sin(\pi x/n)}{\sin(\pi x/n)}$ accomplish it?

Comment: Well, you can define the function $g$ the way how you describe, but what is the question then? If you are looking for some *keyword*, then maybe *restriction* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics) is the right thing. You define $g_n:=f|_{D_n}$, where $D_n=\mathbb{R}\setminus n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: By the way, the domain would have to be written more carefully than you did in your text – it is not a Cartesian product since you take out different set of points for every "slice". So, you need to write it more explicitly as $\{(n,x)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}, x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus n\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Huh that works. I can't believe it's really just that simple.